# OpenCV HOGDescriptor return value

Tags: c++, opencv, int, descriptor

Why does the HOG descriptor returns a vector of `float` and not `int`? It's suppose to return a histogram..

Comment: not sure, just a guess: The histograms might be normalized (e.g. sum of all bins = constant (1?) )

Comment: nope. it's more than 1.

Comment: so maybe a different constant? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that @Micka is right: the histograms are probably normalized (maybe not to 1). On the [Wikipedia page on HOG Descriptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_of_oriented_gradients#Theory), it is written that:

> For improved accuracy, the local histograms can be contrast-normalized by calculating a measure of the intensity across a larger region of the image, called a block, and then using this value to normalize all cells within the block. This normalization results in better invariance to changes in illumination and shadowing.

Hence the need for a `vector<float>` instead of `vector<int>`.

Answer (score 2):

To complement the previous answers that are right in my opinion, according to this [HoG note](https://www.cs.duke.edu/courses/fall15/compsci527/notes/hog.pdf) I found clearer than the initial [Dalal & Triggs paper](https://lear.inrialpes.fr/people/triggs/pubs/Dalal-cvpr05.pdf), there are two normalization steps involved:

- Block Normalization

> Group the cells into overlapping blocks of 2 x 2 cells each, so that
>   each block has size 2C x 2C pixels. Two horizontally or vertically
>   consecutive blocks overlap by two cells, that is, the block stride is
>   C pixels. As a consequence, each internal cell is covered by four
>   blocks. Concatenate the four cell histograms in each block into a
>   single block feature b and normalize the block feature by its
>   Euclidean norm.

- HOG Feature Normalization

> The final normalization makes the HOG feature independent of overall
>   image contrast.

There should be also a bilinear interpolation voting between two consecutive bins to prevent quantization artifacts.

Also, it cannot be an int as you do not only count the number of gradient vectors that fall in a bin but add also the gradient magnitude.